# convert GMT time into Local time in ios

Tags: ios, iphone

i want to convert GMT time into local time . please suggest how to convert this time into current local time in ios application.

please suggest .
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please search before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is it ;

```
 NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
 NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
 [df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];

 //Create a date string in the local timezone
 df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone].secondsFromGMT];
 NSString *localDateString = [df stringFromDate:date];
```